# Seaching a list for more than one string in python

Tags: python, list

I wrote the below function to return True if it detects the string 'Device' in a list

```
def data_filter2(inner_list):
   return any(['Device' in str(x) for x in inner_list])
```

is there a way to search the list for more than one string and return True it it finds either one?

I tried

```
def data_filter2(inner_list):
   return any(['Device' or 'Drug' in str(x) for x in inner_list])
```

But this did not work.

Comment: `'Device' in str(x) or 'Drug' in str(x)`?

Comment: Where's the dupe for... `any(el in text for el in ('string1', 'string2'))`...

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didnt try that @jonrsharpe

Comment: @jonrsharpe With more than two elements this becomes ugly.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that's true, but with exactly two it's neater than nesting!

Comment: @Ev.Kounisif you had more than 2 what is a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: why not to play with return inner_list.index('Device')  or inner_list.index('Drug')?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does \`a == b or c or d\` always evaluate to True?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a binary operator `or` or `and` depending on what you intend, but slightly different from how you've done it:

```
def data_filter2(inner_list):
   return any('Device' in str(x) or 'Drug' in str(x) for x in inner_list)
```

You could use a generator expression, and avoid creating a new list for your check.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the eye

Answer (score 1):

What if you reverse the logic?

```
def data_filter2(inner_list):
   return any([str(x) in ['Device', 'Drug'] for x in inner_list])
```

This provides a framework that can "accept" more items to check for. Chaining `or` is not very pythonic to my eyes.

What is interesting to note here is the following:

```
alist_ = ['drugs', '123123']
astring = 'drug'


for i in range(len(alist_)):
    print(astring in alist_[i])
print('-----')

print(astring in alist_)

#prints:
#True
#False
#-----
#False
```

What this says is that searching for a string in a list requires the strings to be identical (case sensitive) but searching for a string in a string allows for substrings to return `True` as well.

Comment: This isn't strictly the same behaviour as the OP's original

Comment: i would say that this depends on the contents of `inner_list`. Strictly speaking it is indeed different. It will not work if each element of `inner_list` is a line read from a file for example. Boils down to __sub-sets__ and __super-sets__.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis is there a clever way of implementing regex so I dont have to type out Drug and Drugs?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions using `any` and comprenhensions are nice. Another alternative would be to use set intersection.

```
In [30]: bool(set(['aaa', 'foo']) & set(['foo']))
Out[30]: True

In [31]: bool(set(['aaa', 'foo']) & set(['bar']))
Out[31]: False
```

Comment: well this is not equivalent to `in` though. But it might actually be closer to what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line like so:

```
def data_filter2(inner_list):
   return any([x in y for x in ['Device', 'Drug'] for y in inner_list])
```